# Crash in Theano/CUDA exit in cuStreamDestroy

Tags: cuda, theano, cublas

I have an application which is linked against CPython and calls Theano+CUDA code from there.

The application itself also uses CUDA and Cublas. But as they are creating their own handle, I think they should not get into problems.

The GPU is in exclusive mode, i.e. only used by that process. I got that crash both on a Nvidia Tesla K20c and a Nvidia GeForce GTX 680. On Ubuntu 12.04. CUDA 6.0. Latest Theano from Git.

Sometimes, but not always, it crashes when it does the CPython cleanup, where Theano indirectly will cleanup its Cublas handles (see `cublasDestory_v2` in the stacktrace). The CPython cleanup is done in an `atexit` call, maybe that is relevant.

This is the stacktrace:

```
PROGRAM DEFECTIVE (TERMINATED BY SIGNAL):
Segmentation fault

Creating stack trace (innermost first):
#2  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x364a0) [0x2ab5845964a0]
#3  /usr/lib/libcuda.so(+0x1f60f5) [0x2ab586d560f5]
#4  /usr/lib/libcuda.so(+0x20476b) [0x2ab586d6476b]
#5  /usr/lib/libcuda.so(+0x17ac02) [0x2ab586cdac02]
#6  /usr/lib/libcuda.so(cuStreamDestroy_v2+0x52) [0x2ab586ca9b32]
#7  /usr/local/cuda-6.0/lib64/libcublas.so.6.0(+0x206074) [0x2ab57c6ee074]
#8  /usr/local/cuda-6.0/lib64/libcublas.so.6.0(+0x23a87d) [0x2ab57c72287d]
#9  /usr/local/cuda-6.0/lib64/libcublas.so.6.0(cublasDestroy_v2+0x1e) [0x2ab57c536fee]
#10  /home/zeyer/.theano/compiledir_Linux-3.16--generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-12.04-precise-x86
_64-2.7.3-64/cuda_ndarray/cuda_ndarray.so(_Z24CudaNdarray_gpu_shutdownP7_objectS0_+0x15) [0x
2ab598296065]
#11  /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x4f18) [0x2ab5838e4148]
#12  /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x855) [0x2ab5838a46b5]
#13  /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x5c86d) [0x2ab5838a486d]
#14  /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x53) [0x2ab583989083]
#15  /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+0x47) [0x2ab5839899d7]
#16  /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(Py_Finalize+0xca) [0x2ab5838dc57a]
#17  /home/zeyer/sprint-executables/20150127.125851.367a43a.linux-x86_64-standard/NnTrainer/
nn-trainer.linux-x86_64-standard() [0xa0fb2b]
#18  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3b901) [0x2ab58459b901]
#19  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3b985) [0x2ab58459b985]
#20  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf4) [0x2ab584581774]
#21  /home/zeyer/sprint-executables/20150127.125851.367a43a.linux-x86_64-standard/NnTrainer/nn-trainer.linux-x86_64-standard() [0x7b6391]
```

Is this a known error? Where could I even start to try to debug this? How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you have an actual question?

Comment: @talonmies: I always thought that if I present a crash with a stack trace, the obvious implicit questions are: Why do I get this? How do I fix this? But I extended the question.

Comment: @AMostMajestuousCapybara: That's a bit complicated - way too much code. But I think (hope) that the relevant bits are in the stacktrace. Otherwise, maybe you have a guess at what parts of my other code could be relevant?

Comment: @Albert: This is almost 100% guaranteed to be caused by the CUDA context getting torn down before `cublasDestroy` is getting called. The solution is probably to never rely on implicit context establishment or destruction (ie use the driver API) and carefully structure your applications so that all exit paths converge to a single point which sequentially shuts everything down in the correct order. But seriously, this a pretty vague and broad problem definition and I fail to understand how someone could give you a definitive answer based on what you've  posted.

Comment: @talonmies: That comment already helps me. What exactly do you mean by 'CUDA context getting torn down'? What CUDA calls could do that? I would like to post more information but not sure which. The code is way too big and its very hard/impossible to reduce it to a small test case. But maybe you would know relevant parts which I could post or where I could start debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I call `Py_Finalize` earlier now, not via `std::atexit`, and so far, I did not have this crash anymore. So I guess that is the solution.